# Add debit card to paypal?

Tags: paypal

I am trying add debit card in my paypal account I have tried 3 debit cards But the same error occurs for all the cards.

"The bank that issued your card didn't approve this transaction. Please contact the card issuer.s customer service department if you have any questions. Or you can add a different card now to continue."

Please tell what is the problem.

Comment: This is not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: Ok but still I got the answer from a user @AdityaAnjoli

Comment: You got the answer but its the wrong place to ask such a question. I hope you understand.

Comment: Voted to close as it is not related to programming or anything like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your debit card is not permitted to make international transactions that's why is showing this error contact your bank branch to activate international transactions on your card.

Answer (score 2):

There is something called POS(point of sale) facility which is used to shop and make payment, Contact your bank whether it's activated or not.

Answer (score 1):

Some of bank will contact you very soon by call for activate international transaction or not ?
like HDFC , IcIcI bank in india